# Can professional e-mail end with no greeting, or is it too "harsh"?

Tags: email

I heard recently that if no greeting is really necessary, it is just best to end with none at all instead of a greeting with empty meaning, like "sincerely", or "cordially"

Isn't is too harsh to the receiver eyes?

Comment: Ah, that really needs more context. I do programming and quite often there are whole email chains where you just have 1-2 sentences then the answer is 1-2 sentences back and forth a couple of times. Adding a greeting would make this WAY more unreadable and blow it up disproportionally.

Comment: Where are you in the world? Things that are considered polite or normal in some places can be considered rude in others (e.g. the absence of a salutation in an email seems rude and demanding to me, but from my experience dealing with North Americans is normal and considered appropriate in the USA and Canada)

Answer (score 3):

I disagree. Emails are typically less formal than letters so the valediction may be unnecessary but that doesn’t mean it’s always better to leave it out.

Keep the content and audience in mind. “Sincerely” or “cordially” may be a bit formal. When I’m just sending a quick note to a colleague, I usually just use “best regards” or simply “best”. If I’m asking for something I use “thanks.” There’s undoubtedly a cultural component as well so if in doubt, just copy what other people in the organization do.